# returning from a rails method with a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basic question I'm afraid, but I can't find the answer. I have a method on a model called "warning flag". I want to stop the method and return a string given one of a couple of conditions to avoid running the code unnecessarily. so something like

```
def warning_flag
"No flag" and return unless self.active?

...do stuff here
end
```

however, this is clearly wrong. It stops the code, but just returns a nil.

help!

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
def warning_flag
  return "No flag" unless active?

   ...do stuff here
end
```